# How to prevent field to be replaced by objectid field when copying from sde to local file geodatabase

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy

Im copying tables from a sde database to a local file geodatabase using [Table To Table](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/conversion/table-to-table.htm)

First two columns in SDE table when previewed in ArcCatalog:

1. CLASS_ID
2. CLASS_NR

When copied the CLASS ID column is replaced with OBJECTID column, and the values in the CLASS_ID column have been lost.

How can i get the CLASS_ID field to stay unchanged?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Object ID fields](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/using-sql-with-gdbs/object-id.htm) are dynamic in their nature and are used internally by the system. You should not use them as unique ID column. You would normally create a new column, calculate it to contain the ObjectID column values and then use it as your key.

However, I do understand that there are certain circumstances when it might be needed to preserve them (legacy systems, for instance). In these cases, I find it very handy to be able to use `arcpy.RecordSet()` as `Table To Table` will indeed re-index your rows.

The code to run:

```
import arcpy
recs = arcpy.RecordSet(r'Database Connections\sqlgdb.sde\sqlgdb.DBO.KeepOIDs')
recs.save(r'C:\ArcGIS\target.gdb\out_oids')
```

A more complete sample to verify the in/out data:

```
import json
import arcpy

recs = arcpy.RecordSet(r'Database Connections\sqlgdb.sde\sqlgdb.DBO.KeepOIDs')
js = json.loads(recs.JSON)
print [(i['attributes']['OBJECTID'],i['attributes']['CITY_NAME'])
       for i in js['features']]

#[(1, u'Detroit'),
 #(3, u'New York'),
 #(4, u'Philadelphia'),
 #(5, u'Los Angeles'),
 #(7, u'Dallas'),
 #(8, u'Houston')]

recs.save(r'C:\GIS\Temp\test.gdb\local_table')

#testing on local table
local_recs = arcpy.RecordSet(r'C:\GIS\Temp\test.gdb\local_table')
local_js = json.loads(local_recs.JSON)
print [(i['attributes']['OBJECTID'],i['attributes']['CITY_NAME'])
       for i in local_js['features']]
#[(1, u'Detroit'),
 #(3, u'New York'),
 #(4, u'Philadelphia'),
 #(5, u'Los Angeles'),
 #(7, u'Dallas'),
 #(8, u'Houston')]
```

You can see that the ObjetID field values were preserved in their custom order.